# Why does MPC-HC keep forgetting this one particular setting?

Tags: windows, windows-10, media-player-classic

A couple of years ago or something, I learned that MPC-HC has an off-by-default setting which enables YouTube-like "seek bar thumbnails", and I immediately turned it on.

But after some time, it was automatically turned off again, without me doing anything. **None of my many other settings were reset. Only this particular one.**

I have since re-enabled it numerous times, but it just keeps "forgetting" that it's supposed to be on randomly. I never do anything that could explain this. It seems entirely random and unpredictable. No other setting ever resets or changes.

I've updated MPC-HC a couple of times as well, but it never solves it.

What could explain this? How can it be possible that "some" settings (or one specific one) is reset but not all of the rest? This drives me insane.

No other person is physically using or having access to this computer and it's highly unlikely that somebody has a backdoor to it and does this when I look away just to mess with me.

Comment: its perfectly reasonable that a coding error related to just one setting could cause it to be lost or defaulted when other events happen. these events might be an application upgrade, saving another config setting, doing something within the program that is incompatible with that setting so its reset, etc. when you get down to the code, its almost certain that each setting has code that handles it in particular, and there may be bugs in that code.

Comment: @FrankThomas But it happens with no changes to MPC-HC?